# Light terminal-based alternative to gdebi

Tags: software-installation

I post this in order to provide an answer.

Lately I had problems with gdebi on various systems, where installation seemed to go fine but then the program seemed absent. This never happened when I used the terminal for the same purpose of installing from deb files.

Can the terminal be used as a full alternative to gdebi? (that is: install on double click etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `gedit` text editor, in order to associate the deb files with an "application":

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/deb_install.desktop
```

with the lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=[Desktop Entry]
Icon=gdebi
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e "sudo dpkg -i %f"
```

Then, right click a deb file, select "Open with" - "Other application", and select "Install deb".